# A more concise way to reformat dates

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime

I need to convert the date as follows: `2015 June 12 16:00 GMT` -> `2015-12-06`

Is there a more concise way to convert a date?

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = '2015 June 12 16:00 GMT'
date = datetime.strptime(start_date[:-10], '%Y %B %d')
a = date.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
print(a)
```

Output:
`2015-12-06`

Comment: Combine the two lines like `a = datetime.strptime(start_date[:-10], '%Y %B %d').strftime('%Y-%d-%m')`, although your code is compact and readable, IDK why you'd want a  more concise way. Also, not really related to your question but `2015-12-06` is a weird non-standard format. Where might one need the date to be in such a format?

Comment: I don't need this format yet. I was just interested in ways to format the date. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find using [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) more useful when working with datetime strings...

**Code:**

```py
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> start_date = "2015 June 12 16:00 GMT"
>>> print(parser.parse(start_date).strftime("%Y-%d-%m"))
2015-12-06
>>>
```